# Bound for the gradient (or laplacian) of a strictly convex function from above

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $V \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^d; \mathbb{R})$ a (strictly) convex function with $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = 1.$

I am trying to show that
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x V(x) |^2\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx < +\infty.$$
My ideas:
(Due to strict convexity and $V$ is not constant and smooth on $\mathbb{R}^d$ we should have $ \lim_{|x| \to \infty} V(x) = + \infty.$ Perhabs this could be useful...)
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x V(x) |^2\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla_x V(x) \cdot \nabla_x\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \Delta_x V(x) \cdot \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx.$$
If I could estimate $\Delta_x V(x)$ in a certain way like:
$$ \Delta_x V(x) \leq \alpha + \beta |\nabla_x V(x) |^2$$ with $\alpha > 0$ and $\beta \in [0;1) $ it would work. Does this hold for all (strictly) convex functions with $ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx = 1$? The inequality does not hold for all strictly convex functions like for $-\mathrm{ln}(x)$ on $(0, +\infty).$ So I suppose we will need an additional condition.

Or are there any other ideas?

Maybe something like
$$ |\nabla_x V(x) |^2 \leq a + b |V(x)|^2$$ would work too...

Since V is convex and differentiable it fulfills:
$$ V(x) \geq V(y) + \nabla^{\top} V(y) \cdot (x-y)$$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d.$ That should be helpful.

Comment: That was not integration by parts in the first step. It was just use of chain rule:
$$ \nabla_x \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} = -\nabla_xV(x) \cdot  \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)}.$$
Integration by parts is only used in the second step.

Comment: No, obviously not. As I mentioned it is just:

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |\nabla_x V(x) |^2\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx 
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla_x V(x) \underbrace{\nabla_x V(x )\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)}}_{- \nabla_x \mathrm{e}^{-V(x)}} \, dx 
= - \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \nabla_x V(x) \cdot \nabla_x\mathrm{e}^{-V(x)} \, dx.$$

Comment: May I know the source of such result?

Comment: Or is there a counter-example?

Comment: I am curious as to the reason why you are "relatively sure it should apply"

Comment: Are there any papers or materials you encountered which lead to your guess that such a result will hold?

Comment: I came in touch with this in the context of Fokker-Planck equations. This $V$ models a confinement potential in equations like 
$$ \partial_t f(t,x) = \mathrm{div}\left(\mathbf{D}(x)[\nabla_xf(t,x) + f(t,x)\nabla_x V(x)] \right).$$ My main resource was Ansgar Jüngel's Book "Entropy Methods for Diffusive Partial Differential Equations." I am now trying to rigorously work out proofs that are relevant to me. And I need at least $f \cdot \nabla V \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d).$ With $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathrm{e}^{V}dx).$ And this condition would be sufficient.

Comment: Fortunately I have devoted a lot of time on Ansgar Jüngel's Book as well, if I remember correctly in his book no such inequality was stated, are you reading Chapter 2 or Chapter 4 for your question?

Comment: I am reading chapter 2 (The PDE Viewpoint of the Bakry–Emery Approach) and I also considered the original reference "On convex Sobolev inequalities and the rate of convergence to equilibrium for Fokker-Planck type equations." (By Arnold, Markowich, et al.). I was trying to rigorously work out the mass conservation since the equation is in divergence form but to apply the divergence theorem I need at least $L^1$. (Acutally $W^{1,1}$.) I also considered the article "Hypocoercivity for linear kinetic equations conserving mass" (by Dolbeault, Mouhot, Schmeiser) where such a condition is used.

Comment: In "Hypocoercivity for linear kinetic equations conserving mass" (by Dolbeault, Mouhot, Schmeiser) (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.1495.pdf) such condition is used on page 14 as an assumption. But they did not require convexity for $V$. So my thought was that by use of convexity (which is required in Jüngels Book) and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \mathrm{e}^{-V} \, dx = 1$ it should be possible to derive something like that.